# How to build Ivy with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular8

I am using Ivy with Angular Material but When I run `ng build` I got this issue below:

```
ERROR in Tried to overwrite D:/Subin/PROJECTS/angular-ivy-sample/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/table.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.
```

[image]

Any idea to fix it?

I am using **Angular 8.0.0** and **Angular material 8.0.1**.

I found some helpful link but it seems like no solution for this:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29703
2. https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/issues/1400

Answer (score -3):

Try ...

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```